# Python extract numbers from string of alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, regex, string

How do I print the numbers in a string in Python? In the example below, I am able to print the 6. How do I print the 6 and 5 together? Giving me 65.

```
man = 'The man is 65 or older'
print(man[11])
```

Comment: These work great but I need the numbers on the same line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of two ways that *don't* involve hardcoding your index.

#### `str.split` with `str.isdigit`

```
numbers = [x for x in string.split() if x.isdigit()]
print(numbers)
['65']
```

---

#### `re.findall`

```
import re

numbers = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', string)
print(numbers)
['65']
```

<sub>**Regex Details**</sub>

```
\b      # word boundary
\d+     # match 1 or more digits
\b      # word boundary
```

Note that the `\b` word boundary should be used if you want to return only those numbers that are not part of a bigger word (for example, `3D` will not be counted here).

Comment: option 2 is better, since if the numbers are at different places in the string it works perfectly.

Comment: @bulbus Interesting. Why do you say option 2 is better? For `'The man is 65 with 3 legs'` , the output is identical.

Comment: apologies, i mis-understood `string.split()` to splay all chars! you are right both would give the same results.

Comment: For me an issue is the use of `\b` in Option 2.  To solve the OP's immediate need, you don't need the pair of `\b` operators.  It only comes up in situations like, `'The 65 year old man went to a 3D movie.'` where we want to control whether we get `[65]` or `[65, 3]`.  Clearly up to OP.  +1

Answer (score 2):

How about this short code?

```
man = 'The man is 65 or older'
numbers = list(filter(str.isdigit, man.split(' ')))
print(numbers[0])
```

Comment: This question has any other constraint, so I this my answer is not so wrong. he/she ask that *Giving me 65*.

Comment: @Ho0ony Going by your logic, `man[11:13]` should have been a satisfactory answer for you as well :)